# Shell Script passing characters in order from 1-9 and from A-Z

Tags: php, bash, shell

I need to pass a character to a `php` script in a bash script. I want to do this in a loop. it will start with '1' until '9' and than it will continue with 'A' to 'Z'. I've found that bash recognizes character's by their octal `ASCII` code. I think the code will look like this:

```
while true
do
      #There will be a second loop for character iteration here I suppose 
      php index.php char
      #end of the second loop
done
```

*`char` variables used above is the iterator and the parameter for the `php` script

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No need to use the ASCII code here, a `for` loop will do the trick:

```
for char in {{1..9},{A..Z}} ; do
    php index.php $char
done
```

Comment: He wrote `'A' to 'Z'`, so I think he really meant to use capital letters.

Comment: Yes title and question are little different.

Comment: Ah, anubhava you're absolutely right... I forgot to write in capital in the title sorry about that! Thank you for reminding it.

Comment: a little simpler with `for char in {1..9} {A..Z}; do`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for char in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
do
    php index.php "$char"
done
```